# Regex match all inside brackets inside brackets?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to find the following value

```
PROCEDURE test {
        test { }
}
```

from:

```
test {
    PROCEDURE test {
        test { }
    }
}
```

My current Regex is:

```
PROCEDURE.*?{.*?(\}){2}
```

But it does not match. Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this regex:

```
PROCEDURE\s+\w+\s*\{(?:.*?\{.*?\})*.*?\}
```

It matches pairs of {}.

However, if the procedure contains strings or comments that contain curly brackets it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to match pairs of `{` and `}` between the `first {` and the `last }`.

You can try out this regex: -

```
PROCEDURE[^{]*[{](?:[^{]*[{][^}]*[}])*[^}]*[}]
```

I have enclosed curly braces inside character class, so that you don't need to escape them, also with `[^{]*`, you won't need `reluctant` matching, as it will automatically stop at the first `{`.